# C++ "for loop" save data in array then write to file unique data

Tags: c++

I have the following for loop:

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("proc.txt", ios::app);

for (unsigned int i=0; i<res.size(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << res[i] << std::endl;
    myfile << res[i] << "\n";
}

myfile.close();
```

How can I keep all data of `res[i]` into and array or a buffer, then after the loop ends sort out the date, make it unique then print out and save to file (so I don't have duplicate data)?

In my example my code outputs say some numbers like:

`123456
123456
12345678`

but I need only:

`123456
12345678`

My full code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>

void find_locs(HANDLE process) {

    unsigned char *p = NULL;
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION info;

    for ( p = NULL;
        VirtualQueryEx(process, p, &info, sizeof(info)) == sizeof(info);
        p += info.RegionSize )
    {
        std::string buffer;

        if (info.State == MEM_COMMIT &&
            (info.Type == MEM_MAPPED || info.Type == MEM_PRIVATE))
        {
            DWORD bytes_read;

            buffer.resize(info.RegionSize);
            ReadProcessMemory(process, p, &buffer[0], info.RegionSize, &bytes_read);
            buffer.resize(bytes_read);

            const std::tr1::regex rx("(^[0-9]{8,10}$");
            std::tr1::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> res; 
            std::tr1::regex_search(buffer, res, rx);

            ofstream myfile;
            myfile.open ("proc.txt", ios::app);

            for ( unsigned int i=0; i<res.size(); ++i)
            {
                std::cout << res[i] << std::endl ;
                myfile << res[i] << "\n";
            }

            myfile.close;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <process ID>", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    int pid;
    sscanf_s(argv[1], "%i", &pid);

    HANDLE process = OpenProcess(
        PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION,
        false,
        pid);


    find_locs(process);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: res has size() function, what's its current type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could copy your data into a set and then write the content of the set in your file; something like:

```
std::set<int> unique;
std::copy(res.begin(), res.end(), std::inserter(unique, unique.begin());
for (std::set<int>::const_iterator i = unique.begin(); i != unique.end(); ++i)
{
  myfile << *i << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `std::set` seems to do the job, thanks all for answer! I can't set "answered" to all of you, so I will set it for the answer with code example.

Answer (score 2):

You could write into a `std:set<long>` or a `std::list<long>` then sort and run std::list::unique() function to remove all duplicated elements.

As I see `res.size()`, res is one kind of STL container already? if yes, you could simply sort res and call std::unique() algorithm to remove duplicated elements:

```
std::sort(res.begin(), res.end());
std::unique(res.begin(), res.end());
```

see reference:

- [std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)
- [std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)
- [std::list::unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/unique)

Answer (score 2):

Putting it into a `std::set` is probably the best way since it is already sorted and gets rid of duplicates. Later you can simply iterate over it and print